# jQuery toggle function for multiple div's

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, toggle

I have function that shows full content of div.post-text when I click on div.post-read and when click again then hide it.
But something doesn't work right, when I do that with first text everything works great, but if I click on second or third when first is open, then it doesn't slide back or sometimes doesn't open.
What is wrong with my function?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var read = $(".post-read");
        read.click(function() {
            if (read.html() == 'Read more') {
                $(this).html("Show less");
                $(this).prev().removeClass('post-text').addClass('post-text-open');
                $(this).prev().hide();
                $(this).prev().slideToggle("slow");
            } else {
                $(this).html("Read more");
                $(this).prev().removeClass('post-text-open').addClass('post-text');
                $(this).prev().hide();
                $(this).prev().slideToggle("slow");
            }
            });
        });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="posts">
                <div class="post">
                    <div class="post-img">
                        <img alt="" src="img/post-pic.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="post-text">text ... ... ...</div>
                    <div class="post-read">Read more</div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="post">
                    <div class="post-img">
                        <img alt="" src="img/post-pic.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="post-text">text ... ... ...</div>
                    <div class="post-read">Read more</div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="post">
                    <div class="post-img">
                        <img alt="" src="img/post-pic.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="post-text">text ... ... ...</div>
                    <div class="post-read">Read more</div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
.post-text {float: left;width: 457px;padding-left: 16px; overflow:hidden; height:72px;}
.post-text-open {float: left;width: 457px;padding-left: 16px; overflow: auto; height:auto;}
```

Comment: $(this).prev().hide();
$(this).prev().slideToggle("slow");

So you hide it and after its hidden you show it again with a sliding movement.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
if (read.html() == 'Read more') {
```

to this

```
if ($(this).html() == 'Read more') {
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ddHcP/).